# Find conditions on $p,q$ such that $p+q-1<pq-p-q+2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

If $p,q$ are primes with $p<q$, find conditions on $p,q$ such that $p+q-1<pq-p-q+2$?

Now I started slowly with $p=2$ which is the smallest prime.
Then $p+q-1=q+1$ and $pq-p-q+2=2q-2-q+2=q$.

Hence $p+q-1>pq-p-q+2$. So if $p=2$ and $q$ is any prime, then this inequality does not hold. But how do I find all primes $p,q$ for which the inequality holds.

Can someone please help.

Comment: Analyze the case $p=3$ and $p>3$, you are doing right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have, $$pq-2p-2q+3>0$$
Hence, $$(p-2)(q-2)>1$$.
Which is obviously true for all pairs of prime as long as they are not equal to $2$.

Comment: Thank you very much buddy

Answer (score 2):

The condition $$p+q-1<pq-p-q+2$$ is equivalent to $$0<pq-2p-2q+3$$

The right side can be written as $$(p-2)(q-2)-1$$ which is positive iff $p$ and $q$ are odd primes.